# How generate an empty row in the footer of JSF data table

Tags: jsf, footer

I have a JSF table and I want to generate an empty row in footer of datatable (without any data). It is my JSF datatable: I tried several different ways but I cannot generate exactly an empty row in the footer. Please sb gives me a guidance. Really thanks.

```
<h:dataTable value="#{dataGridBean.dataList}" var="item"
                                 headerClass="TR mul_a"
                                 class="sortable multiTable"
                                 id="t"
                                 style=" width: 980px;"
                                 rowClasses="mul_b"
                                 footerClass="mul_c"
                                 columnClasses="sel_kolumna_lp mul_right,mul_left,mul_left,mul_center,mul_left,mul_left,mul_left,mul_left"
                                 >
                        <h:column>
                            <f:facet name='header' ></f:facet>
                                #{dataGridBean.dataList.rowIndex+1}
                            <f:facet name="footer" class="mul_c" ></f:facet>  
                        </h:column>
                        <h:column>
                            <f:facet name='header' >Numer sprawy</f:facet>
                                #{item.numbrSprawy}
                            <f:facet name="footer" class="mul_c" ></f:facet>  
                        </h:column>
                        <h:column>
                            <f:facet name='header' >Typ sprawy</f:facet>
                                #{item.typSprawy}
                            <f:facet name="footer" class="mul_c" ></f:facet>  
                        </h:column>
                        <h:column>
                            <f:facet name='header' >Date rozpoczęcia</f:facet>
                                #{item.rozpoczcia}
                            <f:facet name="footer" class="mul_c" ></f:facet>  
                        </h:column>
                        <h:column>
                            <f:facet name='header' >Zespol</f:facet>
                                #{item.zespol}
                            <f:facet name="footer" class="mul_c" ></f:facet>  
                        </h:column>
                        <h:column>
                            <f:facet name='header' >Nazwisko</f:facet>
                                #{item.nazwisko}
                            <f:facet name="footer" class="mul_c" ></f:facet>  
                        </h:column>
                        <h:column>
                            <f:facet name='header' >Imię</f:facet>
                                #{item.imie}
                            <f:facet name="footer" class="mul_c" ></f:facet>  
                        </h:column>
                        <h:column>
                            <f:facet name='header' >Miasto</f:facet>
                                #{item.miasto}
                            <f:facet name="footer" class="mul_c" ></f:facet>  
                        </h:column>
                        <f:facet name="footer">

                        </f:facet>  


                    </h:dataTable>
                </h:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is that JSF does not render the footer if there is nothing inside it.
If you do not want to add any content to it, just make it visible, then try adding an empty panelGroup with a style like below.

```
<f:facet name="footer">
   <h:panelGroup style="display: block;"/>
</f:facet>
```

Now assuming that your mul_c class has some height and background defined, you should see the footer rendered. 
You could also mark the panelGroup with the mul_c class instead and see the same result.
Hope that helps.